# Word for the occurence of people talking over one another

Tags: single-word-requests

I am evaluating lessons that take place over video conferencing platforms. One frequent problem is multiple students talking at the same time.

I want a word to describe this phenomenon in my reports:

> "a lot of [x]"

So far, I am settling for coining the term 'overtalk'

> "a lot of [overtalk]"

A search for this term suggests that it is used to refer to the act of talking uncontrollably as a function of anxiety.

This is not a problem, as that use is also somewhat uncommon and field-specific, so I'm comfortable coopting the term for this new context.

However, is there a better word already in use for this?

I don't want 'interrupting' as this suggests awareness and disregard on the part of the interrupter that somebody is already talking. I am looking to describe the occurence when multiple speakers happen, unintentionally, to be speaking at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single word, I think people just say "talking over each other"

Comment: In this question's example sentence, I personally prefer *crosstalk* from one of the other question's answers.

Comment: Ah, yes. I've heard crosstalk used before. Perfect. I've upvoted the answer in the other thread. Thanks for pointing it out.